# How can I authenticate using AD with oracle Apex 5?

Tags: oracle-apex

How can I authenticate using AD with oracle Apex 5? It seems that only the built in user authentication is available to do this so I need to know if there is some workaround to do this.

Comment: end user authentication, not workspace authentication?

Comment: yes Login authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are asking about end user 's login authentication I believe you should start from Authentication Schemes.

It is under Shared Components on Apex 4x

You 'll need the host adress of your LDAP directory, DN String and port.

Afterwards, you may also need to set an authorization scheme.